# Can Android voice recognizer return more than one match?

Tags: android, android-intent, speech-recognition

When doing speech recognition using Google's server's via Chrome's HTML 5 speech input support, you get back roughly 6 results each time that are the 6 possible interpretations of the user's voice audio.  When I do the same operation in my Android app, I only seem to get back one.  Is this just the way it is or is there a setting that will cause the Android recognizer intent to return more than one utterance?

Relevant code samples:

```
/**
 * Fire an intent to start the voice recognition activity.
 */
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech reco demo...");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

/**
 * Handle the results from the voice recognition activity.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        // Set the current global speech results to this latest session's.
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

        AndroidApplication andApp = AndroidApplication.getInstance();

        andApp.speechRecoResults.setContents(matches);
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
} // onActivityResult()
```

UPDATE: I added the following line of code to startVoiceRecognitionActivity() as per |Z|*Shadow*|Z| right before the startActivityForResult() call and I get multiple utterances now:

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,5);
```

-- roschler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can return multiple utterances I have a few implementations that do such.  Could you post the code you are using so we could help you out better?

Answer to comment:

Yes and I can set it to return however many the server picks up...I usually just set it to 5. Check my previous post which includes my code of one implementation. [Voice Recognition as a background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372080/voice-recognition-as-a-background-service) This one disables Google's dialog box that pops up when you record. THis line gets the amount of results to return: intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,5)

Comment: Are you using the "free form" speech model in your Android app code?  How many utterances do you typically get back?