# Speech Recognition as a service.(Android)

Tags: android-service, speech-recognition

I am developing android application. I my application I need speech recognition.But I need speech recognition as service. I already create simple speech recognition in which when I click on button it start recognizer intent.It works fine and gives me output. But what I need when user click on button speech recognition start as service (in background).When user start specking it start recognizer and give me output.

I read few question regarding this but not getting proper solution to this kind of functionality. Is there any way to implement this. Need help... Thank you

Comment: Check following link to find the answer

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039429/android-speech-recognition-continuous-service">A good Tutorial</a>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Speech Recognition as a service on Android 4.1 & 4.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2)

Answer (score 3):

There is some code that does exactly what you need here:

https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/activation/SpeechActivationService.java

See it running by downloading this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=root.gast.playground).

The code is a `Service` that runs in the background, listening for the users speech. When the user speaks a certain word, it fires an `Intent`. The `Service` also puts up a handy `Notification` while it is listening. There is some other code that starts and stops it [here](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/app/src/root/gast/playground/speech/SpeechActivationServicePlay.java).

Comment: @nilkash: did u try this. did it work? can you post the final code?

Comment: That's awesome! I have liked. I have just one question: Can I put this into a separate thread in a service? Thanks!

Comment: @gregm . i want to do an app that it recognize user speak. if they are the same, sth happens. and want to do it in background. is yhis code help me? http://stackoverflow.com/q/37225500/4568864

Comment: It isn't possible yet to do speech recognition in the background using Google's tools. Sphinx might work but it has been challenging to get that running.

Comment: I wonder how much strain on the battery this would put, say if I had such an app (service actually) run continuously..

Comment: app link is dead