# Can't start speech recognition in service

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to run the speech recognition api in a service with the code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2/14950616#14950616) and I'm having trouble doing so.

My activity has these lines:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
......

Intent startConstantSR = new Intent("MyService.class");
        getApplicationContext().startService(startConstantSR);
....
}
```

and the Service's onCreate looks like this

```
public void onCreate()
    {super.onCreate();
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE); 
        mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new SpeechRecognitionListener());
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                                         RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                                         this.getPackageName());
      mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
 }
```

I have set up a Toast in onReadyForSpeech and onBeginningOfSpeech to show up so I know that I am on the right path - but no kind of toast is fired.

What am I doing wrong? I can't find out because I'm just barely acquainted with services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to either override onStartCommand in the service to send a listening message or bind to the service and send a listening message

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{

    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING);

    try
    {
        mServerMessenger.send(msg);
    } 
    catch (RemoteException e)
    {

    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

For the bind implementation see [Android Speech Recognition Continuous Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039429/android-speech-recognition-continuous-service)