# using voice/speech recognition to carry out instructions in my app

Tags: android, api, libgdx, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

hello i wanted to ask for some knowledge on using voice/speech recognition to carry out instructions in my game.

I'm fairly new to game development and i am using libgdx to build my game. i know speech recognition api's exist. i would like to know how they work as in how i can integrate them to my game. i would like for the user to be able to say jump and the (player) to jump, the speech commands i want to use are very basic e.g. shoot and the player should shoot a bullet.

If anyone seems to have some knowledge with speech/voice recognition api's i want to know if there's a simple way i could set the speech recognition api i will be using to carry out specific action upon hearing specific keywords such as "jump".

Any answer will be helpful because my knowledge is very limited with using api's and speech recognition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A service would be required to do this. This is basically a class that will run in background and hence will be able satisfy your needs above.

Here is a useful thread that uses a voice recognition service:

[Android Speech Recognition Continuous Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039429/android-speech-recognition-continuous-service?lq=1)