# Continuous Speech recognition Like OK-Google with multi-language

Tags: android, voice-recognition, speech, continuous

i implemented google-speak in my projects but its limitation is its respond only 3 second so i loop the code but some time its not responding properly. Is there any lib or service that give support for continue voice recognize.and also how to stop google beep sound.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465687/start-speech-recognition-thru-voice-with-phrase-like-ok-google

Comment: Hi sir thanks for Replay i already see this but most of dose same. looping code and used Google API and i get same issue that why i post this question. except Responding to magic words like Ok Google

https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo