# Android continuous voice recognition

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I am currently trying to implement android voice recognition for a research project that I am currently working on. I was able to follow a guide and I am able to correctly receive input but I want the phone to continuously look for input instead of telling me to try again after a while. I want to use it to control a moving robot connected to the phone meaning that I won't be able to physically touch the screen. Right now I made it so that if speech is recognized and converted then it immediately calls promptSpeechInput() again but I can't seem to find a way to do that when it runs out of time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039429/android-speech-recognition-continuous-service this might help

Comment: run service in back-end  this might be helpful.!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Speech Recognition Continuous Service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039429/android-speech-recognition-continuous-service)