# Android Voice Recognition as Service with or without Notification

Tags: android, voice-recognition

First of all, I know there is so much questions are already asked about this voice recognition in background or service. I think I've checked all of them in 2 weeks :P. But I did not understand all these answers. I also used there code but it's not working. 
What I want is when user clicks on a button to start voice recognition service then the service starts and even the android is locked the service listen instructions from the user. 
Can somebody tell me how can I achieve this or any tutorials. 
I'm working on this from 2 weeks. I have searched a lot on google and SO also.

==================Update==============================
I'm Calling a Service in MainActivity but the service is started and and also receive the message but the RecognitionListener class methods did not start. I'm using the code from this 
[Android Speech Recognition Continuous Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039429/android-speech-recognition-continuous-service)

Can somebody tell me what's going wrong in my code....

This is MainActivity

```
package com.android.jarvis.voicerecognitionservice;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Messenger;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import static com.android.jarvis.voicerecognitionservice.BuildConfig.DEBUG;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final String TAG = "Service";
    private int mBindFlag;
    private Messenger mServiceMessenger;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//        Intent service = new Intent(MainActivity, RecognitionService.class);
        startService(new Intent(this, RecognitionService.class));
        mBindFlag = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH ? 0 : Context.BIND_ABOVE_CLIENT;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        bindService(new Intent(this, RecognitionService.class), mServiceConnection, mBindFlag);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();

        if (mServiceMessenger != null)
        {
            unbindService(mServiceConnection);
            mServiceMessenger = null;
        }
    }
    private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection()
    {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
        {
            if (DEBUG) {Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected");} //$NON-NLS-1$

            mServiceMessenger = new Messenger(service);
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.what = RecognitionService.MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING;

            try
            {
                mServiceMessenger.send(msg);
                Log.d(TAG,"Message Sent");
            }
            catch (RemoteException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
        {
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onServiceDisconnected");} //$NON-NLS-1$
            mServiceMessenger = null;
        }

    }; //
}
```

This is Recognition Service

```
    package com.android.jarvis.voicerecognitionservice;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.Messenger;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

import static com.android.jarvis.voicerecognitionservice.MainActivity.TAG;


public class RecognitionService extends Service {
    static AudioManager mAudioManager;
    protected SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
    protected Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent;
    protected final Messenger mServerMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler(this));

    static boolean mIsListening;
    static volatile boolean mIsCountDownOn;
    static boolean mIsStreamSolo;

    static final int MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING = 1;
    static final int MSG_RECOGNIZER_CANCEL = 2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
        mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new SpeechRecognitionListener());
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
                this.getPackageName());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    protected static class IncomingHandler extends Handler
    {
        private WeakReference<RecognitionService> mtarget;

        IncomingHandler(RecognitionService target)
        {
            mtarget = new WeakReference<RecognitionService>(target);
        }


        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            final RecognitionService target = mtarget.get();

            switch (msg.what)
            {
                case MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING:

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    {
                        // turn off beep sound
//                        if (!mIsStreamSolo)
//                        {
//                            mAudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
//                            mIsStreamSolo = true;
//                        }
                    }
                    if (!target.mIsListening)
                    {
                        target.mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(target.mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
                        target.mIsListening = true;
                        Log.d(TAG, "message start listening"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                    }
                    break;

                case MSG_RECOGNIZER_CANCEL:
                    if (mIsStreamSolo)
                    {
                        mAudioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, false);
                        mIsStreamSolo = false;
                    }
                    target.mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
                    target.mIsListening = false;
                    Log.d(TAG, "message canceled recognizer"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Count down timer for Jelly Bean work around
    protected CountDownTimer mNoSpeechCountDown = new CountDownTimer(5000, 5000)
    {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {
            mIsCountDownOn = false;
            Message message = Message.obtain(null, MSG_RECOGNIZER_CANCEL);
            try
            {
                mServerMessenger.send(message);
                message = Message.obtain(null, MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING);
                mServerMessenger.send(message);
            }
            catch (RemoteException e)
            {

            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mIsCountDownOn)
        {
            mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
        }
        if (mSpeechRecognizer != null)
        {
            mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
        }
    }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onBind");  //$NON-NLS-1$

            return mServerMessenger.getBinder();
        }


    protected class SpeechRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
        {
            // speech input will be processed, so there is no need for count down anymore
            if (mIsCountDownOn)
            {
                mIsCountDownOn = false;
                mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onBeginingOfSpeech"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech()
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onEndOfSpeech"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error)
        {
            if (mIsCountDownOn)
            {
                mIsCountDownOn = false;
                mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
            }
            mIsListening = false;
            Message message = Message.obtain(null, MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING);
            try
            {
                mServerMessenger.send(message);
            }
            catch (RemoteException e)
            {

            }
            Log.d(TAG, "error = " + error); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            {
                mIsCountDownOn = true;
                mNoSpeechCountDown.start();

            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onReadyForSpeech"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResults"); //$NON-NLS-1$

        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
        {

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to show your code and explain what does not work exactly.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev, I've added code, dude.

Comment: You should have copy the code from the question answer, not the wrong code from the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement an RecognitionService.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionService

There is an demo example from android:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/VoiceRecognitionService/