# Android service not working with bindService()

Tags: android, android-service

Actually I want to do speech to text continuously in the background so actually I am using the solution which is given in the  below link but i m not getting how can i implement it. 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039429/android-speech-recognition-continuous-service?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have done this so far but still my service is not running and i am not getting any output 
So I think that i have done something wrong in its implementation.Please help me and correct my code in order to run service and get my output

This is my mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int mBindFlag ;
private Messenger mServiceMessenger ;

private Button btStartService;
private TextView tvText;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d("check", "onStart: ");

    bindService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class), mServiceConnection, mBindFlag);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (mServiceMessenger != null) {
        unbindService(mServiceConnection);
        mServiceMessenger = null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent service = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    this.startService(service);
    mBindFlag =  Context.BIND_ABOVE_CLIENT;
    Log.d("check", "onCreate: "+mBindFlag);
    btStartService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btStartService);
    tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvText);
    int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {

            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO

    };

    if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    }

}

public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}








private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection()
{

@Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
    {
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.d("check", "onServiceConnected");} //$NON-NLS-1$

        mServiceMessenger = new Messenger(service);
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = MyService.MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING;

        try
        {
            mServiceMessenger.send(msg);
        }
        catch (RemoteException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
    {
        if (DEBUG) {Log.d("check", "onServiceDisconnected");} //$NON-NLS-1$
        mServiceMessenger = null;
    }

};
```

}

This is the code for my background service

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    protected AudioManager mAudioManager;
    protected SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
    protected Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent;
    protected final Messenger mServerMessenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler(this));
protected boolean mIsListening;
protected volatile boolean mIsCountDownOn;

static final int MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING = 1;
static final int MSG_RECOGNIZER_CANCEL = 2;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new SpeechRecognitionListener());
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,
            this.getPackageName());
    Log.d("check", "onCreate: "+"service");
}

protected static class IncomingHandler extends Handler
{
    private WeakReference<MyService> mtarget;

    IncomingHandler(MyService target)
    {
        mtarget = new WeakReference<MyService>(target);
    }


    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        final MyService target = mtarget.get();

        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING:

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                {
                    // turn off beep sound
                    target.mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
                }
                if (!target.mIsListening)
                {
                    target.mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(target.mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
                    target.mIsListening = true;
                    Log.d("check", "message start listening"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                }
                break;

            case MSG_RECOGNIZER_CANCEL:
                target.mSpeechRecognizer.cancel();
                target.mIsListening = false;
                Log.d("check", "message canceled recognizer"); //$NON-NLS-1$
                break;
        }
    }
}

// Count down timer for Jelly Bean work around
protected CountDownTimer mNoSpeechCountDown = new CountDownTimer(5000, 5000)
{

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish()
    {
        mIsCountDownOn = false;
        Message message = Message.obtain(null, MSG_RECOGNIZER_CANCEL);
        try
        {
            mServerMessenger.send(message);
            message = Message.obtain(null, MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING);
            mServerMessenger.send(message);
        }
        catch (RemoteException e)
        {

        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();

    if (mIsCountDownOn)
    {
        mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
    }
    if (mSpeechRecognizer != null)
    {
        mSpeechRecognizer.destroy();
    }
}

protected class SpeechRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener
{

    private static final String TAG = "check";

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech()
    {
        // speech input will be processed, so there is no need for count down anymore
        if (mIsCountDownOn)
        {
            mIsCountDownOn = false;
            mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
        }
        //Log.d(TAG, "onBeginingOfSpeech"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech()
    {
        //Log.d(TAG, "onEndOfSpeech"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(int error)
    {
        if (mIsCountDownOn)
        {
            mIsCountDownOn = false;
            mNoSpeechCountDown.cancel();
        }
        mIsListening = false;
        Message message = Message.obtain(null, MSG_RECOGNIZER_START_LISTENING);
        try
        {
            mServerMessenger.send(message);
        }
        catch (RemoteException e)
        {

        }
        //Log.d(TAG, "error = " + error); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        {
            mIsCountDownOn = true;
            mNoSpeechCountDown.start();
            mAudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
        }
        Log.d("check", "onReadyForSpeech");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),results.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB)
    {

    }

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return mServerMessenger.getBinder();
}
```

}

Comment: @Saswata can u please help me in this

Comment: I have never ran service with bind service but used Intent service, you may try this https://www.journaldev.com/20735/android-intentservice-broadcastreceiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer I have not enabled the service from the manifest