# How to make continuous speech recognition in Android that runs even when the phone is locked?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, background-process, smartphone

I am very new to Android development, and recently I've been working on a project for college using an Android phone that, in sum, is constantly listening for the user's voice until they say a specific word or phrase, and then it executes an action. It has to listen the user even when the phone is locked. As for now, battery consumption is not a concern. 
My issue is I have no idea how to run this on background. I've read about `Services`, `WorkManager` and `JobScheduler`, none of which seems to continuously run speech recognition while the phone is locked. I found similiar questions from several years ago but no definitive answer. 
Is there any way to do this?


Similar questions: 
[Speech Recognition as a service.(Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406925/speech-recognition-as-a-service-android) 
[Android Speech Recognition as a service on Android 4.1 & 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2) 
[Android Speech Recognition Continuous Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039429/android-speech-recognition-continuous-service)

Comment: With Android 9, apps cannot access the microphone in the background: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder If you are wondering how certain devices have "wake words" that work through screen lock, that would be custom software by device manufacturer, or faking a lock screen and being always active, and/or running on older versions of Android.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate, but thanks for the answer.