# Android enable Bluetoothheadset Microphone

Tags: android

I'm making an app which can play music and can switch to talk mode. In talk mode, 
the user will speak into the microphone, and those spoken words will be played back to the speaker in realtime (using AudioTrack).

I've done this function with wired earphones by RecognitionListener

like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372080/voice-recognition-as-a-background-service) but I add some code on function onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) for AudioTrack

but on a Bluetooth headset I can only play music using AudioManager. When I call speechRecognition intent it's work but detect noting from microphone. I think this is because the Bluetooth headset microphone is only enabled during a call.

Is there any way to do this on bluetooth headset ?